# Innodb Engine is crashed

Tags: mysql, innodb

Folks

My server's Innodb Engine is crashed. Please let me know how to repair it.

The screen shot is as attached.

[image]

[image]

I dont have any table backup as well.

dhairya

Answer (score 0):

Check the error.log for more detail. Prior to that make sure backup the entire data directory to diff location. 
 Base on the issue and the level of corruption you can try with innodb_recovery 1-6.